# Problema com .htacess Url

Tags: php, html, htaccess

Boa Tarde pessoal, estou tendo um problema no meu  .htacess, estou fazendo um teste pelo xampp, só que me retorna página não encontrada ou similar, já fiz de N forma e nada, meu .htacess ele tira o final do .php e acrescenta \ não sei o problema é meu index.php, vou enviar os códigos.

.htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remover extensão do arquivo (exemplo: /arquivo.php para /arquivo)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# Adicionar o barra (/) no final do endereço URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# Redirecionar internamente as páginas sem extensão para o arquivo correspondente (crucial para o funcionamento da página)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

index.php

```
<?php
            $url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url']:'home';
            $url = array_filter(explode('/',$url));

            $file = $url[0].'.php';

            if(is_file($file)){
                include $file;
            }else{
                include '404.php';
            }            
        ?>
```

Comment: Olá, explique melhor o que você está tentando fazer, por favor. Se entendi direito, você quer encaminhar todas as requisições para a página 'index.php'. É isso mesmo?

Comment: o problema é que não sei se fiz certo essa parte do index.php , o que quero é ex: http://meusite.com.br (home) quemsomos.php -> /quemsomos  contato.php -> /contato

Answer (score 0):

Já tive um problema parecido e esse .htacess me ajudou muito:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.png -f
```

Esse não é necessário o index.php que você montou, basta colocar a sua página inicial padrão por exemplo:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Olá!</title> </head> <body> </body> </html>
```

Comment: opa, muito obrigado, só uma obs esse seu .htacess ele já oculta .php do final da pagina?

Comment: Sim, oculta o .php

Comment: outra dúvida, no meu caso não preciso chamar essa index.php, posso deixar a home como index.php?

Comment: Sim, pode deixar o home como index.php que irá ler como página principal, não precisa do código que o senhor montou, mas caso queira que de /index vá para /home basta usar um redirect ou header location